# Spring boot shut downs (really) immediately on remote server with no error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment

I have built a jar of a spring application using `package` maven plugin. Locally, I can run it with
`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev target/my.jar`
and **everything works**.

Then I copied the jar to a remote server using `scp`, logged in with `ssh`, copied all resources which my application requires and tried to run. This is what i got:

```
user@server:~$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev target/my.jar -debug
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

[INFO ] 2018-03-01 13:37:02                  com.ws.eb.MyApplication - Starting MyApplication v1.0 with PID 16806 (/home/user/target/my.jar started by suirz in /home/user)
[DEBUG] 2018-03-01 13:37:02                  com.ws.eb.MyApplication - Running with Spring Boot v1.5.9.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.13.RELEASE
[INFO ] 2018-03-01 13:37:02                  com.ws.eb.MyApplication - The following profiles are active: dev
user@server:~$
```

No error message.

I tried with different profiles (dev/test/production), changed owner of files to me and got the same output. I tried to run it with both jdk-9 and jdk1.8. I develop in IntelliJ Idea. What can be different from my local machine? How can I print more information on what's wrong?

I realize that there are many similar questions on SO, but in each of them ther was SOME error messages.

`dmesg` output:

```
[    7.803955] [drm] Max GMR ids is 64
[    7.803958] [drm] Max number of GMR pages is 65536
[    7.803960] [drm] Max dedicated hypervisor surface memory is 0 kiB
[    7.803963] [drm] Maximum display memory size is 4096 kiB
[    7.803966] [drm] VRAM at 0xe8000000 size is 4096 kiB
[    7.803969] [drm] MMIO at 0xfe000000 size is 256 kiB
[    7.806320] [drm] global init.
[    7.808880] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 4087984 kiB
[    7.808884] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 kiB
[    7.808887] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[    7.808897] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[    7.811195] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    7.811202] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    7.812224] [drm] Screen objects system initialized
[    7.812351] [drm] width 640
[    7.812372] [drm] height 480
[    7.812393] [drm] bpp 32
[    7.817482] [drm] Fifo max 0x00040000 min 0x00001000 cap 0x0000077f
[    7.840594] fbcon: svgadrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    7.891478] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x37
[    7.894293] [drm] Initialized vmwgfx 2.6.1 20140704 for 0000:00:0f.0 on minor 0
[    8.003994] AVX version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    8.004001] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    8.156934] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139563.865:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=589 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.156948] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139563.865:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=589 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.156957] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139563.865:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=589 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.157796] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139563.865:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=589 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.157805] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139563.865:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=589 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.158244] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139563.865:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=589 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.188649] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
[    8.269314] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    8.270832] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: intr type 3, mode 0, 5 vectors allocated
[    8.274863] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps
[    8.594646] init: failsafe main process (636) killed by TERM signal
[    8.708205] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139564.413:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=925 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.708231] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139564.413:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=925 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.708246] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139564.413:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=925 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.709706] audit: type=1400 audit(1515139564.417:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=927 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.251903] NET: Registered protocol family 40
[  471.712509] init: tty1 main process ended, respawning
```

(it does not change after executing jar)

**UPDATE**

1. I've created a dummy empty spring project and it works both locally and on a remote server.
2. I've purged maven libraries cache
3. I've recreated my project for scratch and get rid of some dependencies, still no luck

Good news: the recreated project does **not** work locally. Maybe it's something about dependencies, maybe some missing or confilicting jars.

Good news 2: When running spring boot from inside Idea, I get some warning message!

Now the output is:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:44323', transport: 'socket'
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-api.jar,file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/activation.jar,file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jsr173_1.0_api.jar,file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb1-impl.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/user/.m2/repository/org/htmlparser/htmlparser/2.1/htmlparser-2.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/htmlparser/htmlparser/2.1/sax-2.0.1.jar,file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/htmlparser/htmlparser/2.1/htmllexer-2.1.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

[INFO ] 2018-03-05 11:14:03                  com.ws.my.MyApplication - Starting MyApplication on user-msi with PID 5593 (/export/home/workspace/my/employemYackend/target/classes started by user in /export/home/workspace/my)
[DMYUG] 2018-03-05 11:14:03                  com.ws.my.MyApplication - Running with Spring Boot v1.5.9.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.13.RELEASE
[INFO ] 2018-03-05 11:14:03                  com.ws.my.MyApplication - The following profiles are active: dev
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:44323', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My pom files

master

https://pastebin.com/cKAKTriq

new, spring boot application

https://pastebin.com/PBwmH2wZ

old legacy module ("commonJars"), some code dates 2003.

https://pastebin.com/rQ37HNLL

Comment: What does `dmesg` say? It's possible the OS kills the process because of some reason.

Comment: I've run `dmesg` and then tried to run my jar again and it works! Can it be related?

Comment: I doubt that very much. I tried to help you debug, but apparently all you got out of it was "if something doesn't work, try running `dmesg` and maybe it will work afterwards".

Comment: update2: My "hurray it worked" was false positive, I've executed it in a wrong (local) terminal tab. I've just posted dmesg from remote server.

Comment: Are you running your jar file in linux environment? If yes, you should run as a service, not by java -jar..

Comment: Do you know any resource that says this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the problem of absence of logs was in a `logback.xml` which I created to customize log messages. After deleting it, error messages were printed and I was able to resolve actual errors (it was something about tomcat not starting, not really relevant to this question).